# Android ListView from SQLitedatabase with clickable items to delete

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to populate a list of values by querying the SQLite database that I creaed for my Android app. When the user clicks the button (DROP), the activity changes to ListViewDelete that should have the list of all the rows from a Select query based on an ID. I am clueless as to how do I proceed with it. I tried something from a tutorial but my app failed. Here is my code:

--MySQLitehelper.java----

```
public class MySQLitehelper {

//public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "GWid";
  public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "DateGWU";
  public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
  public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UPDTable";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UPDdb_version6";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

  private final Context context;
  GetSet getset = new GetSet();
  public void GetIdForGwid(GetSet get)
  {
     getset=get; 
  }

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                                " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " integer," + COLUMN_DATE + " VARCHAR," +
                                COLUMN_LOCATION+" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_TIME +" VARCHAR);";

//  private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +
//                                              " Values (47688507,'DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";

  private static final String DATABASE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +
          COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )"  +
                          " Values (47688507,'DEC-07-2012','MARVIN 203','20:00');";



  DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
  SQLiteDatabase db;




 public MySQLitehelper(Context ctx)
  {
      this.context = ctx;
      dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
  }



private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
     {
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);            //execute create table
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT);            //execute insert query
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )" +" Values (47688507,'DEC-22-2012','OLD MAIN','23:00');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )" +" Values (1234567,'DEC-14-2012','FUNGER','12:00');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )" +" Values (7654321,'DEC-29-2012','GELMAN','22:00');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +  " (" +COLUMN_ID+ " ," + COLUMN_DATE + "," +COLUMN_LOCATION+" ," +COLUMN_TIME +" )" +" Values (47688507,'DEC-12-2012','IVORY','23:00');");
 }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(MySQLitehelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


// open the DB
 public MySQLitehelper open() throws SQLException
 {
    System.out.println("Inside open function");
     db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
 }

 public void close()
 {
     dbhelper.close();
 }



 public void insertRecord(long gwid, String date, String location, String time)
     {
           ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
          initialValues.put(COLUMN_ID, gwid);
          initialValues.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
          initialValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
          initialValues.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
          db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
     }

public Cursor getAllrows()      //function to get all rows in the DB. Testing initially.
{

     Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME, null);
     return cur;
}

public Cursor getRecord(long getid) throws SQLException
{
        Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_DATE, COLUMN_LOCATION, COLUMN_TIME},
        COLUMN_ID + "= "+getid, null, null, null, null, null);   //HARDCODED. Please make it dynamic
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
 return mCursor;
}

}
```

--SelectOptions.java-- Here the user clicks on the DROP button (btnDrop) and then control goes to the activity ListViewDelete.java which is further below

```
public class SelectOptions extends Activity {

protected static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "This is a the GWID";
Button btnView, btnDrop, btnLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_options);


    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //long getid = intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, defaultValue)
            final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

       if (extras != null) {
           long getid = extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,0);

        }

    btnView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewShift);
    btnDrop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDropShift);
    btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewLocation);


    final GetSet gwid = new GetSet();
/*   ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
        final MySQLitehelper db = null;

        final Dialog diag = null;
        final TextView txt = null;   */
    final MySQLitehelper helper = new MySQLitehelper(this);



    btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            helper.open();
            Cursor c = helper.getRecord(extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
        //  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         //    Cursor cursor = helper.query(constantValues.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "emailid"},null, null, null, null, null); // here emailid is the field name in the table and contantValues.TABLE_NAME is the table name 
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             do {

                 System.out.println("In Do while");
                 DisplayRecord(c); 

             } while (c.moveToNext());
          }
            helper.close(); 
            System.out.println("Out of Do");                

        }  
    });


    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(SelectOptions.this, MapViewActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent2);
            startActivity(intent2);


        }
    });

    btnDrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(SelectOptions.this, ListViewDelete.class);
            //startActivity(intent2);
            intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
            startActivity(intent3);

        }
    });
}




public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
{
    System.out.println("In side toast display function");
    Toast.makeText(this, "id: "+c.getString(0)+"\n"+
            "Date: "+c.getString(1)+"\n"+
            "Location: "+c.getString(2)+"\n"+
            "Time: "+c.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

--ListViewDelete.java

```
public class ListViewDelete extends ListActivity {


String []list =  {"A","B","C","D"};    //#I just tried to populate a sample list#




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_delete);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    //gets the GWID

    final MySQLitehelper dbhelper = new MySQLitehelper(this);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
    Cursor c = dbhelper.getRecord(extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                System.out.println("In Do while");
                // DisplayRecord(c); 
                //list[]

                } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    dbhelper.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list_view_delete, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The above class needs to be restructured and I don't seem to be on track. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle things like these imo is to use a listview backed by a `cursorAdapter` as opposed to one backed by another sort of adapter. Here's a restructuring of the ListViewDelete class to include the `simpleCursorAdapter`. The downside would be that you have to know the id's of the textViews that the adapter is going to be writing to. The benefit is that you can refer right to your database rows with the adapter to effect it.

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter; // < --- make sure it's this one

...

public class ListViewDelete extends ListActivity {

    private MySQLitehelper dbhelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_delete);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    //gets the GWID

        dbhelper = new MySQLitehelper(this);
        Cursor c = dbhelper.getRecord(extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));

        //    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to, flags) 
        //    ^ I wanted you to see the parameters

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.delete_activity,
                // ^ custom xml holding a layout to be used for each row of your listview
                c, 
                new String[]{MySQLitehelper.COLUMN_DATE, MySQLitehelper.COLUMN_LOCATION, MySQLitehelper.COLUMN_TIME},
                // ^ an array of the database columns that you want
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3},
                // ^ the textView ids (in your custom layout) that you wanted the columns to be mapped to 1 to 1 
                0);
        // ^ just put 0 for that


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void refreshListview() {
        Cursor c = dbhelper.getRecord(extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
        adapter.changeCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // where the delete action is gonna take place
        dbhelper.deleteRow(id);
        // when they click a row, the database will delete by id
        // which the onListItemClick method conveniently provides with a cursorAdapter
        refreshListview();
        // then we refresh the listview to see the changes.
        // you might want to make an "delete? are you sure?" dialog or something for your own implementations.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list_view_delete, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dbhelper.close();
    }
}
```

And the deletion method in the MySQLitehelper database class that is being referred to:

```
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But i used it in a different way. I passed the a list of retrieved values from the SelectOptions class intent to the ListViewDelete intent and i can successfully do it. But your answer is helpful too.